# Algorithm for change specific color of when rendering

Tags: image, algorithm, fonts, colors, textures

Given that I have a texture file generated from a font bitmap builder like this:

[image]

Now I load it into my program. Then, I want to write my text with different colors rather than black such as blue, pink, ... from that original texture file.

What trick or algorithm should I use?

Any one can help me, please

Thank you very much.

Comment: What tools are you using? OpenGL? DirectX? Core Graphics? GDI? What OS? What have you tried? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a white version with transparency, you can use hardware vertex blending to get any color you want, but as I said, the text has to be white. Doing it in a software loop is possible, but only with brute-force.. Even if you use a library, it will only be scanning every pixel in, converting it, and re-writing it again... Which is slow. So use hardware vertex coloring.